# Line up image vertically with bottom border of header using Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm developing a website where I've separated text on one side and images on the other using Bootstrap rows and columns.

I have the following layout in my HTML file:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
        <h1>This is a very long header with underline</h1>
        <h3>This is a subheader</h3>
        <p>This is a description</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
        <figure class="figure">
            <img src="/assets/contentImage4.jpg" alt="Placeholder" class="img-fluid img-thumbnail content-image">
            <figcaption class="figure-caption">A caption for the above image.</figcaption>
        </figure>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the associated CSS:

```
.figure {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 45px;
  margin-bottom: 45px;
  width: 40%;
  text-align: center;
}

h1, h2 {
  font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
  border-bottom: 4px solid black;
}
```

I have offset the figure's top margin by 45 pixels to get the top of the image to align with the black underline underneath the h1. However, on long titles (like in this case) the h1 wraps to take up two lines, meaning the photo is no longer lined up. Is there a way to get this to fit programmatically based off the way h1 is wrapping?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are really familiar with bootstrap but in your markup you haven't specified the number of columns you want each of your divs to take.
Bootstrap's Grid system is made of 12 columns so you have to specify how many you need to occupy. 
In this case you would do something like:

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
```

This just took 4 of the 12 columns in the bootrap grid, you can use the other 8 for the image div.

In Bootstrap 4 I believe the way you formatted it means each div will take half of the space essentially meaning it would be equivalent to 6 columns each.

Comment: Yes, I intend for the two columns to be the same width. The issue is related to the height of the image, not to the width of the column containing it.